# Showing that $p$ is a cluster point of a subset $S$ of metric space $E$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

**Q:** Let $S \subset E$ and $ p \in E$. Show that $p$ is a cluster point of $S$ $\iff$ $p$ is the limit of a Cauchy sequence of points in $S \cap \{p\}^c$

**A:** Assume $p$ is a cluster point of $S$. Then $B(p, \frac{1}{n})$ contains an infinite number of points in $S$. Now using the definition of a Cauchy sequence, given any real number $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $d(p_n,p_m) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ when $n,m>N$

I am stuck as to how to continue this proof (if i am starting it right) and how to prove it in the other direction.. Can someone please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting out right.

For any $\epsilon$ let N > $\frac 2 {\epsilon}$.  Then n > N means 1\n < $\epsilon$/2.  Now as p was a cluster point $B(p, 1/n)$ have infinite points of S.  Label one as $s_n$ and find another in $B(p, 1/(n+1))$ and label is $s_{n+1}$.  These {$s_n$} make a Cauchy sequence. as $d(s_n, s_m) < d(s_n, p) + d(p, s_m) < \epsilon/2 +\epsilon/2 = \epsilon$.

If {$s_n$} $\rightarrow$ p is a Cauchy sequence then for any $\epsilon$ there is an N s.t, all n >N imply $d(s_n, p) < \epsilon$.  That means all infinite $s_n \in B(p,\epsilon)$.  So p is cluster point

It's subtle. If you blink you miss it.

Comment: what do you mean by $s_n$? is that just one of the many points in S? @fleablood

Comment: In the first case:  Given cluster point => there is a Cauchy sequence. The {$s_n$} are simply points we selected.  These points will form a Cauchy sequence.  In the second case: Given a Cauchy sequence => p is a cluster point, these {$s_n} are the points of the given Cauchy sequence.